# Zipping two lists in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists of Integer values:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
```

I want to zip the above two lists so that the  elements in even index are obtained from the sum of corresponding elements in List 1 and List 2 and the odd elements are obtained by multiplying them, I tried to do something like this but it did't work:

```
list1.Zip(list2, index => index % 2 == 0 ? (a, b) => a + b : (a, b) => a * b );
```

desired output

```
{ 12,24,16,56,20,96,24,144,28,200 }
```

Comment: what is the current output from the code being tried

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @juharr right, my bad :D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad by output, i mean the desired output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `Zip` first then use the overload of `Select` that includes the index.

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (a,b) => (A:a, B:b))
    .Select((x, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? x.A + x.B : x.A * x.B);
```

Note I'm using value tuples here, so depending on your version of C# you might need to use anonymous classes instead `(a,b) => new { A=a, B=b }`

Comment: This is better than the other answers as it does not access list2 from within the LINQ expression.

Comment: Why not use parameter resultSelector of Zip to do the  "=> i%2 ? x.A + x.B : x.A * x.B" part. That way you don't have to add a Select

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Because `Zip` doesn't have an overload that includes the index.

Comment: Oops, my fault.

Answer (score 3):

`Zip` method doesn't have overload which supports index, you can use `MoreLinq` library or [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) method instead (with element selector, which supports index)

```cs
var result = list1.Select(
        (value, index) =>
            index % 2 == 0 ? value + list2[index] : value * list2[index])
    .ToList();
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

It'll work if both lists have the same length and give you an expected output `12, 24, 16, 56, 20, 96, 24, 144, 28, 200`

Another option is to `Zip` both lists into list of anonymous objects, then calculate the sum against them

```cs
var result = list1
    .Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .Select((value, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? value.a + value.b : value.a * value.b)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Select()` instead of `Zip`

```
var result = list1.Select((e, i) =>
                 i % 2 == 0 ?  e + list2[i] : e * list2[i])
                 .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
int index = 0;
var zipped = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => index++ % 2 == 0 ? a + b : a * b);
```

Succinctly, but it uses a side effect, which is of course bad.